# What is the reason to hide the bundle identifier when they are appeared on the screenshot of Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Sometimes I can see people ask questions about Xcode with a screenshot which contains the bundle identifiers of the app (e.g.:com.mycompany.myappname), but some of them would mask the bundle identifier, what is the reason? is there any security issue when the bundle identifier currently using is exposed?